# Can No Escape counter planeswalker Sarkhan?

Tags: magic-the-gathering, mtg-planeswalkers

Can [No Escape](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bNo%20Escape%5d) counter the planeswalker [Sarkhan the Masterless](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bSarkhan%20the%20Masterless%5d)'s ability that  created a 4/4 red dragon creature?

Comment: Welcome to the site! Please make your question clearer by clarifying which Sarkhan planeswalker you are referring to and by fixing the sentence structure.

Answer (score 4):

[No Escape](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bNo%20Escape%5d) can target the casting of a planeswalker such as [Sarkhan the Masterless](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bSarkhan%20the%20Masterless%5d), but it cannot counter Sarkhin's ability that creates a 4/4 dragon creature. This is because No Escape can only target *spells* to counter then, but activating Sarkin's ability is not a *spell*, it is an activated *ability*.

Spells and abilities are separate things, even when they could both result in a similar outcome like creating a dragon creature. In order to counter an ability, you would need a card that allows you to do so, such as [Stifle](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bStifle%5d).